# How do I wire a door bell?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, doorbell

Can anyone make an educated guess on how to wire so the door bell rings?

The flat used to have door phone entry system, but it doesn't work anymore. So it is used as normal bell. In flat we had a phone, but builder removed when fixing the wall. Now I have 4 cables sticking out with no bell, I need to install a bell using these cables.

4 cable colours: blue, white with blue stripes, orange, and white with orange stripes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the use of these colours are standardised (outside of use in plain old-fashioned land-line telephone systems).

I would disassemble the other end and see how the wires are connected up there. Most likely, two are connected to a push-to-make switch.

If you are sure the system is unpowered, you could use a multimeter to check all 6 combinations of two from four wires for DC voltage and, if no voltages present, check all 6 combinations for changes in continuity when the call-button is pressed.